# Не работает сортировка wp?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Сделал сортировку, но она у меня выводит неверно.
Не могу понято в чём может быть проблема.

```
<?php
                global $wp_query;
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'otkuda', # тип записи
                    'post_status' => 'publish', # статус записи
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => array(
                        'title' => 'ASC',
                    )
                ));
                
                $all = '';
                $n = 0;
                
                
                if ($query->have_posts()):           

                    while ($query->have_posts()):
                        $query->the_post();
                
                        $first = mb_substr( get_field('marshrut', $post->ID)['geo_from']['city_from'], 0, 1 );
                        $n++;
                        $pos = strpos( $all, $first );
                
                if ($pos === false) {
                      if( $n != 1 ) {
                        echo '</div>';
                      }
                    $all .= $first;
                    echo '<div class="other__item">';
                    echo '<div class="title__text">' . $first . '</div>';
                    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="other_link">' . get_field('marshrut', $post->ID)['geo_from']['city_from'] . '</a>';
                } else {

            echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="other_link">' . get_field('marshrut', $post->ID)['geo_from']['city_from'] . '</a>';

          }


                        ?>
                    <?php endwhile;
                
                    wp_reset_query();
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                

                endif; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так он выглядит, а есть ещё места, где оно сливается, тобишь по букву И идут слова на букву К